# moving git hub repo from personal to org

Tags: git, github

I have been building a package on my personal repo. Now I want to move this repo into organization.

Lets assume the name my personal repo is `stack-data`

there is an org exist Research, how do I get `stack-data` under `Research`. I know how to do if I were to start originally under Research org. Which is you create slack-data under `Research`, fork it to your personal and then create pull-requests for each submission.

I did some research: Here are the links that I found:
https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-transfers/

it would be great to hear what is the best practice of doing this and if you can provide an example thats even better.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you wish to get as an answer. The process has been outlined in those links and in [this one](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account/#transferring-a-repository-to-another-user-account-or-to-an-organization) there are actual steps mentioned. What kind of best practices you expect to have?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Full backup GitHub repository

```
git bundle create stack-data.bundle --all
```

**Step 2.** Restore

```
git clone stack-data.bundle
```

**Step 3.** Change remote URL

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.org.here
```

(You also don't use step1,2,3; only change remote URL, then push to remote URL)

**Step 4.** Add `git://new.url.org.here` become submodule of `Research`

Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: not really clear what you meant here: (You also don't use step1,2,3; only change remote URL, then push to remote URL). Are you saying i can do without doing step 1 and 2.

Comment: You clone remote GitHub repository to local Git repository in a specific folder. Inside local folder, you type command: `git remote set-url origin git://new.url.org.here`.

Comment: is step 4 missing a `git add`?